# Accessing JSON feed data

Tags: json, cocoa, parsing, feed

I have an iOS app set up to download and parse a JSON feed. It fetches data fine, but I am struggling on how to read certain nested JSON data of the feed.

Here is the JSON feed I am trying to load:
http://api.wunderground.com/api/595007cb79ada1b1/conditions/forecast/q/51.5171,0.1062.json

The part of the JSON feed I am trying to load is:

```
"forecast":{
    "txt_forecast": {
    "date":"1:00 AM BST",
    "forecastday": [
    {
    "period":0,
    "icon":"chancerain",
    "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/chancerain.gif",
    "title":"Thursday",
    "fcttext":"Clear with a chance of rain in the morning, then mostly cloudy with a chance of rain. High of 59F. Winds from the SSE at 5 to 10 mph. Chance of rain 60%.",
    "fcttext_metric":"Clear with a chance of rain in the morning, then mostly cloudy with a chance of rain. High of 15C. Winds from the SSE at 5 to 15 km/h. Chance of rain 60%.",
    "pop":"60"
    }
```

You see there is a bit called "period":0 and in period 0 there is "icon", "title" etc...

Well I am trying to access that data but I can't.

Here is my code for accessing a certain part of the nested JSON feed:

```
NSError *myError = nil;
NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&myError];
NSArray *results = [res objectForKey:@"current_observation"];
NSArray *cur = [results valueForKey:@"weather"];
NSArray *windrep = [results valueForKey:@"wind_string"];
NSArray *UVrep = [results valueForKey:@"UV"];
NSArray *othertemprep = [results valueForKey:@"temperature_string"];
NSString *loc = [[results valueForKey:@"display_location"] valueForKey:@"city"];
NSString *countcode = [[results valueForKey:@"display_location"] valueForKey:@"country"];
```

How can I change that to access what I want?

Here is my other attempt:

```
 NSString *test = [[[results valueForKey:@"forecast"] valueForKey:@"period:0"] valueForKey:@"title"];
```

Thanks for your help, Dan.

Comment: I can't see `display_location` or `country` in your JSON dump. Might want to paste all the relevant parts of it.

Comment: @DrummerB I have now updated the post with the full code.

Comment: Where does it fail? Put a breakpoint on the first line and go through it step by step.

Comment: What have you tried??  I don't see any reference in your code to "forecast", or from there to "forecastday".  (Or did you just want someone to write the VERY SIMPLE code for you?)

Comment: Well here is my attempt at forecast:

 NSString *test = [[[results valueForKey:@"forecast"] valueForKey:@"period:0"] valueForKey:@"title"];

Comment: Do you know how to [read JSON](http://www.json.org/)?  The `[` indicates you have a JSON array.  You're no doubt getting a "unrecognized selector" message -- NSArray does not recognize valueForKey.  And "title" is is not subsidiary to "period" -- they are "siblings" in the same dictionary.

Comment: (Actually, you're probably coming up with a nil, since you fail to access "forecastday" at all.)

Comment: ***LEARN HOW TO [READ JSON](http://www.json.org/)*** -- it's not that hard.

Comment: Right, thanks for the link. I'll have a read.

Comment: (By the way I am completely new to JSON).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`period` is just a key in the first dictionary contained in the `forecastday` array, with a value of 0. It doesn't identify the dictionary in any way.

To get the title value in the first element of `forecastday`, your code should look like this:

```
NSString *title = results[@"forecast"][0][@"title"];
```

Or, if you're not using the new subscripting syntax:

```
NSString *title = 
  [[[results objectForKey:@"forecast"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"title"];
```

Comment: Back when I was first learning how to parse JSON feeds, I found your answer really hard to understand. But now that I look back at it, its so simple. Thanks :)